# HibernateQueryException: Unable to locate class

Tags: java, hibernate

In the hbm.xml, after an enhancement, I have 2 mapping entry for the class ABC, both are mapped to the table ABC_TABLE

```
<class entity-name="ABC" name="model.ABC" table="ABC_TABLE">
<!-- property tags and id tag -->
</class>

<class entity-name="LazyABC" name="model.ABC" table="ABC_TABLE">
<!-- property tags and id tag -->
</class>
```

Before the enhancement, the hbm.xml only have the entity-name="ABC" mapping for the ABC class.

After such enhancement,
the original HQL query code

```
select new ABC(a.abcId, a.abcContent, a.abcEnding) from ABC a where....
```

throws exception when executed.

The exception is

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateQueryException: Unable to locate class [ABC]
```

caused by

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate class [ABC]
```

Then I found solution on internet, just to change the ABC constructor name to full path of the class, like

```
select new model.ABC(a.abcId, a.abcContent, a.abcEnding) from ABC a where....
```

Then the problem is fixed and no exception is thrown in executing the query!

But, I just don't know why the hibernate handling is like that.

Can somebody tell me the underlying reason why it would be the solution?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all if you need object based results. Use `Criteria` API.

You may have a valid import for `ABC` class. But `HQL` doesn't know the package name of the class, **Because it is String**. So you should provide the complete path including package name.